# Writing python script for a Mac on a linux or windows machine

Tags: python, multiplatform

I wrote a python script for a friend to make a job task easier. Now her company wants to pay me for another script (woot!). However she works on a Mac and I have only a Windows pc and an Ubuntu pc. While python is multi-platform, I ran into a problem with the first script that was only happening on her Mac. So is there a (hopefully free) way to emulate OS X on a Windows PC or Ubuntu, so I can test my script on a mac before hand, without having to give it to her and say 'ok this might work'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions about OS emulators are probably better placed at http://superuser.com (but I'm pretty sure there isn't a free OS X emulator around).

What issues did you encounter? As long as you're not using OS-specific functions, you should be fine. Maybe some encoding issues (windows-1252 vs. UTF-8) could arise, but all of this is speculation until you describe your problem in greater detail.

Comment: Ok, I will ask this at superuser as well. I was using EasyGui to provide File Open boxes and in Windows it worked fine, but under Mac, the File Open box appeared with all the files greyed out and not able to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you stick to the common and POSIX/UNIX interfaces, it will work equally fine on both Ubuntu and OS X barring any deep magic. Since you haven't described the problem, that's the only advice that can be given.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking, perhaps, for recommendations for software that would allow me to emulate OS X on Windows or Ubuntu. I haven't found any through a cursory google search and it came to mind that others may have faced the same problem.